# Initialize Polymorphic Variable on Stack

Tags: c++, c

Coming to C++ with a Java background, I'd like to set up some polymorphic code by initializing a variable of type `A` with one of two implementations, `B` or `C`.

My question is whether there is an easy way to do this *on the stack.*  I have a case where I'm only using `A` inside the method body, and want it destroyed at the end of the function, so touching the heap is optional.

Here's how I would do it on the heap:

```
A* a = NULL;
if (p) {
  B* b = new B();
  b->setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
  a = b;
}
else {
  a = new C();
}

doSomething(a);
delete(a);
```

In practice I'd probably pull this out into a factory method, and use an `auto_ptr` to avoid the `delete(a)`.

This works, but can I do it on the stack?  My thought pattern is something like this:

```
A* a = NULL;
if (p) {
  B b;
  b.setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
  a = &b;
}
else {
  C c;
  a = &c;
}

doSomething(a);
```

Now I don't have to bother with `delete(a)`, but `doSomething(a)` won't work, since the `B` or `C` is destroyed when they go out of scope.

I've been trying to figure out a way to do part of it with the ternary operator as well, but I end up both borking up the syntax and taking the address of a temporary -- so am I right that there is no way to do this?

```
A * const a = &(p ? B() : C());
```

Advice on whether it's a silly idea to implement polymorphism on the stack in the first place is welcome, but mostly I'm trying to better understand the limits of C/C++ in this area, independently of design sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this cleanly using [`std::aligned_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) for storage:

```
template <typename...T>
using storage_t = typename std::aligned_union<0, T...>::type;
```

and a custom `unique_ptr` deleter:

```
struct placement_deleter {
  template <typename T>
  void operator () (T* ptr) const {
    ptr->~T();
  }
};

template <typename T>
using stack_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, placement_deleter>;
```

Resulting in the usage:

```
storage_t<B, C> storage;
stack_ptr<A> a;
if (p) {
  auto b = new (&storage) B();
  a.reset(b);
  b->setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
} else {
  a.reset(new (&storage) C());
}

doSomething(*a);
```

[See it live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2f178064d1ed20a).

Comment: This comes closest to doing what I originally imagined cleanly, and avoid the try-catch in Jeff's answer.  In practice, though, I went with Nemo's answer, using the heap.

Comment: I would put `a.reset(b);` before the `setSomethingImplementationSpecific();`.  If that method throws, we do want `~B()` called.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++11, you can get "stack semantics" by using a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a = (p ? new B() : new C());
```

Although the object itself will still be allocated on the heap.

`std::auto_ptr<A>` is the equivalent idiom in C++03.

Comment: -1 Re `const A &a = (p ? B() : C());`, while reference binding does work that way, the choice operator doesn't.

Comment: that fix takes care of the choice operator's type requirements, but are you sure about lifetimes and UB?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, quite sure. Read Q&A number 3 in [Herb Sutter's old article](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). Do I need to cite the spec myself to get you to remove your downvote?

Comment: Well that's what I meant when I wrote "reference binding works that way". However, the choice operator does not work that way. If you do this for a function actual argument then you're technically on safe ground, because those temporaries last until the end of the full expression. A temporary in a sub-expression of an initializer also has that lifetime. Which is a bit too short.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot do what I was trying to do without slicing the object. I believe the behavior is defined -- the relevant temporary's life cannot end until the containing "full expression" completes, and binding to a const reference extends that -- but the conditional operator + initializer slices the object.

Comment: Consider the case where the base class is abstract. Then it cannot be instantiated. Hence no base class temporary to receive a slicy copy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, now I am unsure again... Example: http://goo.gl/Y1GI0n Every compiler I have tried does "the right thing" with this example, and does not complain even with `-Wall`. Which does not prove anything, of course, but makes me unsure what the standard requires. I think I shall make this a question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this original code,

```
A* a = NULL;
if (p) {
  B* b = new B();
  b->setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
  a = b;
}
else {
  a = new C();
}

doSomething(a);
delete(a);
```

you can do this:

```
void doSomething( A const& ) {}

void doBeeDoo( B&& b )
{
    b.doSomethingImeplementationSpecific();
    doSomething( b );
}

void foo()
{
    if( p ) { doBeeDoo( B() ); } else { doSomething( C() ); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with `boost::optional`:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

void example(bool p) {
  boost::optional<B> b;
  boost::optional<C> c;
  A* a = nullptr;
  if (p) {
    b = B();
    b->setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
    a = b.get_ptr();
  }
  else {
    c = C();
    a = c.get_ptr();
  }
  doSomething(a);
}
```

Note that `b` and `c` must have a long-enough lifetime.  But only one of them calls a constructor and destructor for `B` or `C`.

Comment: The implementation of boost::option uses placement new to keep things on the stack.  So this is very similar to the accepted answer, but requires allocating memory for both a B and C even though only one or the other is used.

Answer (score 1):

What you have won't work. `b` and `c` will be deleted from the stack by the time you get to `doSomething(a);`. However, you could do this:

```
if (p) {
  B b;
  b.setSomethingImplementationSpecific();
  doSomething(&b);
}
else {
  C c;
  doSomething(&c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd thought of that, but was hoping to avoid the redundant calls to doSomething.